# Why my footer jumps into center of the page, when i change window - width size?

Tags: html, css, height, margin

I can't solve problem with footer. I want to make responsive design of the page. When i make width 970 and less, it seems like my all elements get in center of the page as layers, and ignore all previous properties as margin or padding. But when width is more than 970, everything looks as i want it to be.

[image: how it looks with normal width]

[image: width less than 970]

I thought when window width is lower, it should simply stretch or decrease elements size, not put everything in one place..

Here is the code of the page.

```
<body>
<div id="main" class="section-library">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <header class="section-library-header">
                    <h1 class="v1"><i class="ico-library"></i>Sections 
                      Library</h1>
                </header>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="section-library-perex">
                    <p><big>Find tutorials, documentation, downloads, troubleshooting acrticles, and more...</big></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="slidingBox" class="hidden"></div>
    <header class="section-library-header">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>
                <span class="h4">Select Section</span>
                <div id="mobileSelect" class="hidden">
                    <a class="popup-section-toggle" title="Select Section">
                        <span class="arrow"></span>
                    </a>
                    <span id="sectionTypeSelect"></span>
                    <select id="sectionTypes" onchange="changeText();">
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div id="additionalSelect" class="">
                    <img src="images/selectArrow.png">
                    <select id="selectWBttn" onchange="separateButtons(this);">
                    </select>
                    <ul>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </h2>
            <div class="header-image" id="main-icon">
                <img src="" alt="...">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="popup-section js-box-toggle-box">
            <ul class="reset">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="profile-img">
                            <img src="" alt="...">
                        </span>
                        <span class="profile-name">Standardized: 
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                        <span class="profile-img">
                            <img src="" alt="...">
                        </span>
                        <span class="profile-name">Build-up: 
   <strong>Steel</strong></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                        <span class="profile-img">
                        </span>
                        <span class="profile-name">Standardized: 
     <strong>Timber</strong></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                        <span class="profile-img">
                        </span>
                        <span class="profile-name">Parametric: 
     <strong>Thin-Walled</strong></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="reset">
                <li>
                     <span class="profile-img">
                            <img src="" alt="...">
                        </span>
                        <span class="profile-name">Standardized: 
              <strong>Steel</strong></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                      <span class="profile-img">
                            <img src="" alt="...">
                        </span>
                        <span class="profile-name">Build-up: 
        <strong>Steel</strong></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                        <span class="profile-img">
                        </span>
                        <span class="profile-name">Standardized: 
         <strong>Timber</strong></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <!--<li>
                        <span class="profile-img">
                        </span>
                        <span class="profile- 
  name">Parametric: <strong>Thin-Walled</strong></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>-->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container container-section-library">
        <div class="row row-section-library">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-left-section-library">
                <div class="section-library-iconbox">
                    <ul class="reset crossroad-icons" 
  id="sectionCategories">
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="box-std box-std--section-library white" 
  id="currentFilter">
                    <h4 class="std-header">Filter</h4>
                    <form data-ajax-form-action="xhr/selectbox.json" 
          class="form-std">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inp-3-1">Region</label>
                            <div class="select">
                                <select name="inp-3-1" id="inp-3-1" 
               class="form-control">
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inp-3-2">Manufacturer</label>
                            <div class="select">
                                <select name="inp-3-2" id="inp-3-2" 
                class="form-control">
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inp-3-3">Standard</label>
                            <div class="select">
                                <select name="inp-3-3" id="inp-3-3" 
                    class="form-control" data-provide="dependecy" data- 
             dependency="#inp-3-2">
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="inp-3-4">Species</label>
                            <div class="select">
                                <select name="inp-3-4" id="inp-3-4" 
                       class="form-control" data-provide="dependecy" data-dependency="#inp-3-3" data- 
                 empty-value="Select...">
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="btn-wrap">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default 
            btn-submit">APPLY</button>
                            <button id="resetButton" type="reset" 
 class="btn btn-reset" onclick="sectionResult()">RESET</button>
                        </p>
                    </form>
                </div>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-main-section-library" id="sectionLayout">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-middle-section-library">
                        <h1 id="titleBox"></h1>
                        <p class="perex">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla non sollicitudin magna. Morbi vitae semper augue. Mauris semper tempor interdum. Cras eget volutpat metus, nec facilisis justo.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row second">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-middle-section-library">
                        <div class="box-section-library">
                            <h2 id="select-section-series" class="title title-list"><span class="letter-list">A.</span> Select section series</h2>
                            <table class="table-section-library scrolled-tbody">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="tsl-check active">
                                            <label for="inp-all" class="inp-item" id="inp-1">
                                                <input name="inp-all" id="inp-all" type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll();">
                                                <span>inp-all</span>
                                            </label>
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="tsl-series active" onclick="sortSeries(this)">
                                            Series
                                            <!-- <span class="sort sort up"></span> -->
                                            <!-- <i class="arrow up" id="orderArrow"></i> -->
                                            <img class="sort-arrow" src="images/arrowWhite.png">
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="tsl-standard" onclick="sortSeries(this)">Standard
                                            <img class="hidden" src="images/arrowBlue.png">
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="tsl-manufacturer" onclick="sortSeries(this)">Manufacturer
                                            <img class="hidden" src="images/arrowBlue.png">
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="tsl-region" onclick="sortSeries(this)" style="text-align: center;">Region
                                            <img class="hidden" src="images/arrowBlue.png">
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="hidden" onclick="sortSeries(this)">Shape
                                            <img class="hidden" src="images/arrowBlue.png">
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="hidden" onclick="sortSeries(this)">Manufacturing Type
                                            <img class="hidden" src="images/arrowBlue.png">
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="sectionBody">
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-section-library box-section-library-material">
                            <span id="noResultWarn" class="hidden">No matches were found</span>
                            <p class="btn-wrap btn-wrap-inline">
                                <!-- btn-wrap btn-wrap-inline -->
                                <button type="button" class="hidden" id="addButton" disabled onclick='addSelectedProfiles(); hideShowButton();'>Add serie to the list</button> <!-- btn btn-default -->
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-right-section-library">
                        <div class="section-library-detailbox">
                            <div>
                                <h3 id="Picture-title"></h3>
                                <figure class="sl-detail-box--image">
                                    <img src="" alt="..." id="picture">
                                </figure>
                                <div class="inner-title">
                                    <h4 id='innerTitle'></h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="inner-footer">
                                    <ul class="">
                                        <li><strong id='foot-standard'></strong></li>
                                        <li><strong id='foot-section'></strong></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <p class="btn-wrap" ">
                                    <button onclick=" showSerieButton(this)" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id>Show serie</button>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="hidden">
                    <!-- row section-library-selected-profiles -->
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-middle-section-library">
                        <h2 class="h1">Selected series</h2>
                        <div class="selected-profiles-box" id="profileList">
                        </div>
                        <p class="btn-wrap">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="showButton" onclick="changeLayout(); readTableXml();" disabled>Show sections</button>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="accessBar">
                    <p class="btn-wrap">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-inactive" id="showSelected" onclick="showSelected(); changeLayout(); " disabled="">
                            <!-- btn btn-default btn-lg -->
                            Show selected Section
                        </button>
                    </p>
                    <p class="reset-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-inactive-reset" id="resetSelected" onclick="resetAllChecked('sectionBody');" disabled>
                            Reset Selected
                        </button>
                    </p>
                    <p class="btn-top" onclick="toTop();" title="To top">
                        <img src="images/toTopA.png">
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hidden" id="slidingBar">
            <!-- row section-library-function-row -->
            <div id="tablesScroll">
                <div class="additional-scroll">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 section-library-function-row-box">
                <p class="btn-wrap">
                    <button id="selectedProfiles" class="btn btn-inactive" onclick="hideNotSelected()" disabled="">Show Selected Section</button> <!-- btn btn-white has-icon icon-eye -->
                    <button id="resetAllSelected" class="btn btn-inactive-reset" onclick="resetAllTableButton();" disabled=""><span>Reset Selected</span></button>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 section-library-function-row-box">
                <p class="btn-wrap" id="btnWrap1">
                    <button class="btn btn-white has-icon icon-arrange-h" onclick="arrangeColButton();" id="arrangeButton">Arrange table columns</button>
                </p>
                <!-- <p class="btn-top" onclick="toTop();" title="To top">
                                    <img src="images/toTopA.png">
                                </p> -->
                <p class="btn-wrap" id="btnWrap2">
                    <span class="title">Export:</span>
                    <a class="btn has-icon icon-pdf">PDF</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn has-icon icon-xls" onclick="Exc(this);">XLS</a>
                    <!-- <span class="separator separator-v">|</span> -->
                </p>
                <p class="btn-wrap" id="btnWrap3">
                    <a href="#" class="btn has-icon icon-print">Print</a>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden" id="arrangeTable">
                <table class="table-section-library table-horizontal">
                    <thead>
                        <tr id="arrangeColumns">
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
                <a class="close" onclick="arrangeColButton();"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- ------------Footer begins----------------------- -->
    <div class="footer info">
        <div class="section-library-footer" onclick="visibleList('c')">
            <div class="section-library-footer-header">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="box-footer-header col-md-3">
                            <h3 class="title"><i class="ico-library"></i>Sections Library</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-footer-header col-md-4">
                            <h3 class="title">DUENQ</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-footer-header col-md-4">
                            <h3 class="title">DICKQ</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section-library-footer-links">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="sl-box-footer-links col-md-3">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <div class="inner-body">
                                    <div class="inner-text">
                                        <div class="text">
                                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vel massa sit amet lectus
                                                euismod cursus. Aenean orci metus, venenatis commodo mauris vel.</p>
                                            <ul class="">
                                                <li>Standardized: <strong>Steel</strong></li>
                                                <li>Build-up: <strong>Steel</strong></li>
                                                <li>Standardized: <strong>Timber</strong></li>
                                                <li>Parametric: <strong>Thin-Walled</strong></li>
                                                <li>Cold-formed: <strong>Steel</strong></li>
                                                <li>Build-up: <strong>Timber</strong></li>
                                                <li>Parametric: <strong>Timber</strong></li>
                                                <li>Parametric: <strong>Massive</strong></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sl-box-footer-links col-md-4">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <div class="inner-body">
                                    <div class="inner-text">
                                        <div class="text">
                                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vel massa sit amet lectus
                                                euismod cursus.</p>
                                            <ul class="links">
                                                <li><a href="#">More information</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="illust">
                                        <img src="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="sl-box-footer-links col-md-4">
                            <div class="inner">
                                <div class="inner-body">
                                    <div class="inner-text">
                                        <div class="text">
                                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut vel massa sit amet lectus
                                                euismod cursus. Aenean orci metus, venenatis commodo mauris vel.</p>
                                            <ul class="links">
                                                <li><a href="#">More information</a></li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="illust">
                                        <img src="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <div class="to-top-link">
                <a class="js-to-top" onclick="toTop();">
                    <div class="arrow"></div>
                    <span class="text">Top</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="footer-top">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <h2 class="heading">Social</h2>
                            <div class="crossroad-social">
                                <ul class="reset">
                                    <li><a class="facebook" href="#"><span class="sr-only">Facebook</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="twitter" href="#"><span class="sr-only">Twitter</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="google" href="#"><span class="sr-only">Google+</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="linkedin" href="#"><span class="sr-only">LinkedIn</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="youtube" href="#"><span class="sr-only">YouTube</span></a></li>
                                    <li><a class="chat" href="#"><span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col-sm-2 -->
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-6">
                            <h2 class="heading">Products</h2>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <ul class="reset links">
                                        <li><a href="#">Maecenas id nunc</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Duis interdum dolor</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Vestibulum facilisis</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Aliquam justo</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Nam vitae arcu vulputate</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Aliquam varius diam eget</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <ul class="reset links">
                                        <li><a href="#">Maecenas id nunc</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Duis interdum dolor</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Vestibulum facilisis</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Aliquam justo</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Nam vitae arcu vulputate</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Aliquam varius diam eget</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <ul class="reset links">
                                        <li><a href="#">Maecenas id nunc</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Duis interdum dolor</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Vestibulum facilisis</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Aliquam justo</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Nam vitae arcu vulputate</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Aliquam varius diam eget</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.col-sm-6 -->
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-4">
                            <div class="box-footer-contact">
                                <h2 class="heading">Contacts</h2>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <p>
                                            <strong></strong> <br>

                                        </p>
                                        <p>

                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <p>
                                            <strong></strong> <br>

                                        </p>
                                        <p>

                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.row -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.footer-top -->
                <div class="footer-copy">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <p></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-7 right">
                            <ul class="reset menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Impressum</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">AGB</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Datenschutz</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Webshop</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Newsletter</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.footer-copy -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.container -->
        </div>
    </div><!-- /.container -->
    <!-- ---------------------------------------------Footer ends------------------------------------------ -->
</div>
</div><!-- /#main -->
```

JsFiddle is really laggy because of the huge css file, and I'm sorry for that.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/91d834te/)

I am fresh in HTML/CSS, so i need some tips guys.

Comment: That's an awful lot of code. Please note that we expect users to create a [mcve], which requires *slimming down* your code to the bare minimum required to reproduce the problem. That increases the chances that people will help to debug your issue. Dumping your entire site's HTML, CSS,  and JS here just doesn't work well.

Comment: I think you should learn `Mobile responsive css` this solution will not learn you.

Comment: Learn here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_intro.asp

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have written lot of CSS code, where you have even overridden existing grid structure classes, which are not recommended. 
You can learn how RWD works here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/